# Why is the location returned by GL function call -1 if there's no error?

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, compute-shader

In the following program the last print function prints -1 which is the location of the uniform named num. I gave right arguments to the function glGetUniformLocation(), yet got -1 as a result , can't figure out why?

P.S. The shader compiles successfully.

```
        GLuint program = glCreateProgram();
        GLuint computeShader = glCreateShader(GL_COMPUTE_SHADER);

        const GLchar* const shaderSrc = {
            "#version 310 es\n"
            "\n"
            "// Input layout qualifier declaring a 16 x 16 (x 1) local\n" "// workgroup size\n"
            "layout (local_size_x = 16, local_size_y = 16) in;\n"
            "uniform int num;\n"
            "\n"
            "void main(void)\n"
            "{\n"
            "//Do Nothing \n"
            "}\n"
        };

        glShaderSource(computeShader, 1, &shaderSrc, NULL);
        glCompileShader(computeShader);
        int result;
        glGetShaderiv(computeShader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &result);

        if(result == GL_FALSE){
            int length;
            glGetShaderiv(computeShader, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &length);
            char* message = static_cast<char*>(malloc(length));
            glGetShaderInfoLog(computeShader, length, &length, message);
            __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO, "MyLog", "Shader Compile Error:  %s", message);
            free(message);
        }

        GL_CALL(glAttachShader(program, computeShader));
        GL_CALL(glLinkProgram(program));
        GL_CALL(glValidateProgram(program));
        GL_CALL(glUseProgram(program));
        auto location = glGetUniformLocation(program, "num");
        __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO, "MyLog", "Location %d", location);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The uniform variable `num` is not an active program resource, because it is not used in the shader program. The compiler and linker optimize the code and determine that the variable is not required. Therefore, you will not get a valid uniform location.

Comment: Did I get it right? Is the variable optimized out because it's not used?

Comment: got it, will try it out

Answer (score 3):

Besides [@Rabbid76's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67673302/2327517) I want to specifically address the question in your title:

> Why is the location returned by GL function call -1 *if there's no error*?

Because there is no error, and location -1 is **not an error condition**.

Only *active* uniforms do have a location. Querying the location for something which isn't an active uniform is defined to return `-1`. Also note that the following:

```
glUniform1f(-1, someValue)
```

is perfectly valid in the GL and will also not generate any errors as per the spec. It will just be silently ignored.

Since for a non-active uniform variable it is *impossible* to ever influence the outputs of your shader program, its value is irrelevant anyway, and the GL does not have to bother.

Note that this design choices in the API are quite reasonable. On the client side, you can use a set of uniforms you want to provide to your shaders. But you can have different alternatives for these shaders, each accessing a specific sub-set of those uniforms. The client side code can treat each of the variant the same, it does not have to know (or query) which uniforms each uses. It only must not treat location -1 as an error, as it isn't one. At least not if your client code can't be absolutely sure that this variable *must* be active.

**Warning: querying the value of non-active uniforms actually is an error!**

If you use functions like `glGetUniformfv(program,location,params)` with `location` set to `-1`, this actually **is** an error condition. The call will just return `GL_INVALID_OPERATION` and have no other effect (this also means that contents of the memory pointed to by `params` will not be modified - it won't return any default values for such things). This behavior is also quite reasonable, because as non-active uniform variables can't have a value, you cannot query them, and trying to do so is an error.

**Warning: the situation is slightly different for vertex attributes**

For vertex attributes, there is `glGetAttribLocation`, and this will also return `GLint`, and use `-1` for attributes which don't exist or are not active. Querying these also is no error. But the GL functions which take those attribute locations (like `glVertexAttribPointer`, `glEnableVertexAttribPointer`) often use `GLuint` types, and

```
glVertexAttribPointer(-1, ...);
```

*will* generate a `GL_INALID_VALUE` GL error, as `(GLuint)-1` is most likly greater than your implementation's `GL_MAX_VERTEX_ATTRIBS` value (and even if it weren't you're not getting the results you intented.

So for attribute locations, it is mandatory that your client code checks for `-1`...

Comment: Yeah I encountered this glUniform1f(-1, someValue) in the continuation of the program.

Comment: in the same example when I try glGetUniformiv(program, location , &res) where location is the location of uniform num(correct location) and res is just a GLint It doesn't change the value of res to uniform's actual value

Comment: No, it doesn't. Because `glGetUniform1v` actually generates the `GL_INVALID_OPERATION` error. I updated my answer to address this point.

Comment: but in my case it's not -1, it generates no errors but also doesn't change the res variable

Comment: @ErikNouroyan Please create a new question for this issue, since that is complewtely separate from this question, and give the neccessary details to reproduce your problem.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67676989/how-can-i-get-the-ssbo-information-form-compute-shader